# Lightest UI Element

Tags: ios, element, calayer, light

I'm trying to figure out what UI element would be the least significant in lowering the performance of an application when all I'm setting will be either the background color or an image. I won't need any user interaction from the element. I only need the content of the element to show on the screen.

From what I've learned so far, CALayers are very light and I'm comfortable using them, but are they the lightest UI element I can use for simple display use cases?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the "lightest" element?  The one that uses the least amount of memory?  The highest-performing one?  The one with the fewest members?

Comment: Wouldn't those nearly always go hand in hand? The less data there is, the less that has to be loaded and the less that is required from the device to work with it. I guess I'm still too new to ask a proper question, but why are you writing my question off instead of trying to help it?

Comment: Closing isn't permanent.  Make your question clearer and more specific.  Tell the community why "Lightest" is important, and they can provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, I found that CALayers are the lightest for getting the job done in terms of performance, but UIView isn't much heavier at all, but it has a lot more functionality to it.

As for UIImageViews, they are much heavier, but they have a lot of built in methods to make image manipulation easy.

I hope this can help someone!